# Which one is better user defiend types in swift for memory management ? Enum ,Struct or class in swift?

Tags: ios, swift, swift2, swift3

I am confused about user defined type.

In below code Structure ,Class, and enum all are works fine for me.

QUES : 
**1) which one should i use ? 
2) which is better for memory management?**

```
  // By Struct :
    struct IndexStruct{

        static var Tab:Int{
            return 0
        }
        static func methodStruct(string:String){
            print(string)
        }
    }
    // By Enum :
    enum IndexEnum{

        static var Tab:Int{
            return 0
        }
        static func methodEnum(string:String){
            print(string)
        }
    }
    //By class:
    class IndexClass{

        static var Tab:Int{
            return 0
        }
        static func methodClass(string:String){
            print(string)
        }
    }
    // call Index:
    class demo{

        func callValue(){

            print(IndexEnum.Tab)
            print(IndexEnum.methodEnum(string: "Enum"))

            print(IndexStruct.Tab)
            print(IndexStruct.methodStruct(string: "Struct"))

            print(IndexClass.Tab)
            print(IndexClass.methodClass(string: "Class"))

        }
    }
```

Comment: I have the same question regarding memory management of Structure, Class and Enum while we can use all three in above scenario.

Comment: In your example, you only use static variables and static function. Therefore, you don't really use *class*, *struct* or *enum* except for name scoping. So, no memory management is involved and your question is not applicable. Change your example so it uses member variables and member functions and creates instances of the classes, sturcts or enums. Then the question makes sense.

Comment: Possibly related: [Swift constants: Struct or Enum](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38585344/swift-constants-struct-or-enum).