# Using global constants in Swift

Tags: swift

While programming in Java there is common solution for cleaner code when we use static constants like this:

```
public class Game {
    private static final int MAX_PLAYERS_NUMBER = 1000;
}
```

I like very much this approach and I wanted to cast it somehow to Swift.
So I started from static constants:

```
class Game {
    static let maxPlayersNumber = 1000
}
```

It looks good, but it's weird in code when I always have to use class name in non-static methods:

```
func doSomething() {
    print(Game.maxPlayersNumber)
}
```

So I thought about two approaches, one is just simple property in class:

```
class Game {
    let maxPlayersNumber = 1000
}
```

And second is use global constant in file:

```
let maxPlayersNumber = 1000

class Game {}
```

Still I'm not sure what is the best solution for using constants in methods.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to define global constant across the project you should use struct rather then class as Apple suggested.

```
struct AppConstant {
    static let constant1 = 100
}
```

If you want constant across the class you should just define a property with let as you have defined at last.

```
 class Game {

    let maxPlayersNumber = 1000

    func doSomething() {
      print(maxPlayersNumber)
    }
 }
```

Comment: I know that there is no problem with performance and memory now, but is it really good approach to load these constants everytime when creating instance of this class? I always thought that because static constants are loading only once with class is really better. I'm talking while using constants only in one class.

Comment: yes there will be no performance issue because xcode's current mode is constant so if you define a variable at that time first compiler consider it as a constant, if you have defined a variable and you are not mutating it compiler will give a warning that you should make it constant. So it's default mode is constant. There should be no impact on performance if you are creating constant as a property.

Comment: Oh right, seems reasonable, I'm accepting your answer.

Comment: Or an `enum`:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38585344/swift-constants-struct-or-enum.

Answer (score -1):

You may create a new file inheriting from NSObject and declare the constants in this file as below:

```
public static let maxPlayersNumber = 1000
```

here, maxPlayersNumber can be accessed throughout your project scope in the following way :

```
Constants. maxPlayersNumber
```

where `Constants` is the name of the file and `maxPlayersNumber` is the constant declared in the file.

Comment: First of all using class name Constants for all constants would be horrible idea while creating bigger project. Secondly still I have to use class or struct name before constant.

Comment: Constants name was just an example for your reference. You may use anything as you want.