# What's the difference between a struct with only type functionality, and a class with only type functionality?

Tags: swift

For example, consider this class:

```
class Foo {

    private init() {

        // Private init, so no instances can be created.
        // All methods and properties will by owned by the type.
        // So no instances will need to be created,
        // as there is no instance functionality.

    }

    static var count = 0
    static func increment() {
        Foo.count += 1
    }

}
```

Perhaps it makes no difference whether it's a class or a struct? (assuming inheritance isn't needed).

Comment: So... why aren't you using a static class? You can't make an instance of a static class, so it seems like that'd match your use case.

Comment: @cwharris I haven't heard of a static class before (I first thought you meant a class with all static members), but according to this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42935707/are-static-classes-supported-by-swift/42935763, Swift doesn't have them.

Comment: excuse me. I was filtering questions incorrectly. ignore my comment entirely.

Comment: This is an uncommon pattern, enums with no cases are better candidates for namespacing.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38585344/swift-constants-struct-or-enum