# Struct , class or enum for service object with static methods?

Tags: swift, class, struct, enums, static

I want to build a service object with only static methods. Should I use struct or class or enum for this case? What the difference will be? May be it affects compile time? May be it affects speed somehow? I know structs are faster for instances. But how it affects this case?

Your thoughts? You experience?

Thank you.

```
struct/class/enum Linker {

    public static func skypeCall(contact:String) {
        //...
    }

    public static func phoneCall(phoneNumber:String) {
        //...
    }

    public static func openWebPage(url:String) {
       //... 
    }
}
```

Comment: Or enum, compare [Swift constants: Struct or Enum](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38585344/swift-constants-struct-or-enum) – which applies to static methods as well.

Comment: @JAL Actually, this can be based on fact. There is a very limited set of considerations. You can objectively compare the differences in the choices.

Comment: @JAL, so you want to say, there's no facts does it affects performance or not?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are two key difference between a class and a struct in Swift. A class allows for inheritance and a class is a reference type while a struct is a value type.

Make your decision based on those few differences.

Since everything in `Linker` is static, the difference between reference and value becomes irrelevant since you won't have any instances.

So that leaves inheritance. Will you ever subclass `Linker`? If not, use a struct. If yes, use a class.

And now that you are asking about enum, you can probably rule that out over struct since `Linker` doesn't appear to have any constants, just methods.

Comment: thank you for an answer. I thought so. I just wondered does this decision can affect more than just convenience, code style, inheritance, autocomplete variants etc...