# "static let" vs "let" for declaring class specific constants

Tags: swift, static, compile-time-constant

```
class CurrencyConverter {

    // 1
    private let conversionRate = 1.3 

    // 2
    private static let conversionRate = 1.3

    func convertToForeign(fromlocal local: Double) -> Double {
        return local * CurrencyConverter.conversionRate
    }
}

let c = CurrencyConverter()
print(c.convertToForeign(fromlocal: 5))
```

With reference to the code snippet above, assume that I need to use the constant `conversionRate` ONLY in an instance method.

What are the pros & cons of declaring `conversionRate` as only (1)`let` vs (2)`static let` ?

Which style would be more readable & optimised?

Additionally, let's say I will only need 1 short lived instance of `CurrencyConverter` and `conversionRate` itself is bulky (an array of 10K Doubles). Will (1)`let conversionRate` be more memory optimised?

Comment: Personally I would not use `static` just because I don't have to write the class name all the time.

Comment: When you use `static let` you are saying that this value is global and will be the same for all instance of your class but when you use `let` only your are saying that the value is constant for an instance. Now in your case there is no practical difference since you instantiate the property with a hardcoded value but at least `static` tells you something about the purpose of the property.

Comment: See also [Swift constants: Struct or Enum](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38585344/1187415).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Neither.  Use an uninhabited (caseless) `enum` to create a `Constant` namespace; it reads better.

```
class CurrencyConverter {
    private enum Constant {
        static let conversionRate = 1.3
    }
    func convertToForeign(fromlocal local: Double) -> Double {
        return local * Constant.conversionRate
    }
}

let c = CurrencyConverter()
print(c.convertToForeign(fromlocal: 5))
```

Comment: I like this style. However let's say I will only need 1 short lived instance of this class and conversionRate itself is bulky. Will "let conversionRate" be more memory optimised?

Comment: @Raunak I would declare your conversionRate  as static property extending Double `extension Double {
    static let conversionRate = 1.3
}` this way you can do `local * .conversionRate`

Comment: @Raunak the compiler loads and generally. deduplicates all constant primitives into a symbol table, so the 1.3 is in memory no matter what; its not like it loads it from disk when you ask for it.  So it does't matter if its an instance or static constant -- they compile to the same thing,  Thats not true if this were a class like a UIImage because then the data actually does load from disk,

Answer (score 2):

In the code below,

```
private let conversionRate = 1.3
```

the above is an instance variable, i.e. it will last as long the *instance* of `CurrencyConverter` (`c`) exists. Once `c` goes out of scope, `conversionRate's` scope also ends.

Whereas, in the below code

```
private static let conversionRate = 1.3
```

Here `conversionRate` is associated with the `class CurrencyConverter` and not the *instance*. So, it will remain in memory even if the instance `c` goes out of scope, i.e. as long as the app runs.

So, creating *instance variable* is more optimized than creating the *static variable*.

Answer (score 0):

If you add `static` to the `class` `method` or `field` then it is called `class` `field/method`, with this you can access it without creating an `instance` of the `class`.

Without `static` keyword the `field/method` will be `instance` `field/method` , and this is accessible only by creating the instance of the class.

In this case it’s better to go with `static` field as it’s not dependent on other class `fields/methods`, also it’s memory efficient if you have many objects of same class.

Comment: my question clearly says: "assume that I need to use the constant conversionRate ONLY in an instance method"

Comment: If you know the difference between static and none static, then it will be clear whether go for static or none static.

Comment: And also depends how many objects you are creating of this class.