# Static properties in enum

Tags: swift, enums

```
private enum ViewMetrics {
    static let fontSize: CGFloat = 24.0
    static let spacing: CGFloat = 16.0
}
```

Can you explain this for me?

How can we write an enum without cases and how it is possible to define static properties in an enum. I did not find this topics in apple official guide. 
Can anyone help me with the correct reference to know this topic.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38585344/swift-constants-struct-or-enum

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why shouldn't you be able to do this?

Swift enums are first-class types, just like `struct`s and `class`es. Swift `enum`s do not need to have cases, they can be completely empty types, just like how a `struct` or `class` does not need to have any properties.

```
enum Empty {} // completely valid
```

`enum`s cannot have _ stored instance properties_, but they can have *type properties* (which `static` properties are) and computed instance properties.

Caseless enums with static properties are often used for storing constant values. For more information on the topic, see [Swift constants struct or enum](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38585344/swift-constants-struct-or-enum)

This might not be documented in the [Enumerations](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Enumerations.html) section of the Swift docs, but nothing says that this shouldn't be possible either. On the other hand, the docs do state that enums are first-class types and there is a non-exhaustive list of features that enums share with classes and structs.

Answer (score 0):

An `enum` without any case can have `static properties` because they are not related to a case of the `enum`. Just like a `struct` without any properties or an empty `class` having a `static properties`. `static` is not based on an instance of something.

Here is the [link](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Methods.html) for swift documentation which explains clearly about instance and static properties.