# Confused by the usage of a class or a struct as container for static variables (Swift)

Tags: swift, class, enums, containers

In my app I currently use a separate `class` to store a bunch of static variables that I want to access from anywhere at anytime.

```
class Sounds {
    static var soundInitial : Sound!
    static var soundThunder : Sound!
    static var soundWind    : Sound!
    // etc... (about 50 more)
}
```

This `Sounds` class is **never being used as an instance**, but figures as a container for all the sound-effects (which are of type `Sound` - which is a separate class)

I initialize all the sound-effects from the Main View Controller during `viewDidLoad`:

```
let urlPath1 = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "art.scnassets/sounds/my_sound_file", withExtension: "mp3")
Sounds.soundInitial = Sound(url: urlPath1!, volume: 1.0)
// etc...
```

Then I can use it at any given time like so:

```
Sounds.soundInitial.play(numberOfLoops: -1) // endless looping
```

My very basic question as a *not-yet-so-well-experienced-programmer*:

**Is there a more common approach or better way to store all my sound variables centrally together?** *(I don't want to define them in View Controller, because this would give me too much variables there...)*

I found out, that I could use a `struct` to achieve the same. But would this be a better approach?

Is there a special **Container Object** in Swift designed for such purposes?

Comment: If you use a class or struct for this then you should declare a private init so no instances can be created, `private init() {}`. But a more common approach is to use an enum for your static variables (just replace the word “class” with “enum” in your code above).

Comment: This works like charm. So easy. Perfect comment!

Comment: Related: [Swift constants: Struct or Enum](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38585344/1187415)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you're doing is clumping global constants into a namespace.

> Is there a special Container Object in Swift designed for such purposes?

Yes, a caseless enum is the conventional way to do this, as it is the most lightweight and cannot be accidentally instantiated; it is "pure" namespace.

If you watch some Apple videos you'll see that's how they do it. Personally I used to recommend a struct but I've switched to using enums for the reason given.

Comment: This works like charm. So easy. Perfect answer!